# Unable to find postgresql-client-10 on Debian Stretch ARM

Tags: postgresql, debian

I am trying to build docker image on Apple M1 chip Mac and one of the steps include installing `postgresql-client-10` package. The base image is `ruby-2.6.5-stretch` and I have added file repository configuration and repo signing key as listed on postgresql [documentation page for Debian](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/). In the last step, when I am trying to install a specific version `postgresql-client-10`, the build errors out because it is not able to find this package.

This was working fine on AMD Debian Stretch build but not finding this client on ARM Debian stretch. If I install `postgresql-client` (without specifying version), it installs version 9. Is it possible that the client is not available for versions 9 and above? Where can I get the list of available client versions for postgresql based on Debian releases?

There's one more caveat, when I try to install it on `Buster` release, the installation is successful but since I need to have `libproj12` (due to gem dependency), `libproj.so.12` file is not found. Since the [libproj package list for version 12](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libproj12) shows only stretch release, I think I am confined to using stretch release only and have to make it work for postgresql 10.

Comment: welcome to [so], a programmer's forum. it seems your question is not related to programming. you might have more luck on [sf] or {unix.se].

Comment: and why can't you use `postgresql-client-11` (which is supported by Debian proper, and does not rely on some whacky upstream repository)?